# Alternative Function for EREGI in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

I was making a contact form again and eregi() is being used on it. But as we all know, the eregi() function has been deprecated on PHP 5.3 so I want to know what alternative function/s can I use to replace the function eregi()? I've tried !preg_match and even though I get the desired output, there appears to be an error still! >3<

> **Warning:** preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Wall\mailform.php** on **line 38**
>   (Possible spam attempt detected. If this is not the case, please edit the content of the contact form and try again.) - The sentence inside the () is the desired result.

This is the codes I used. !preg_match() used to be eregi(). :)

```
function spamcheck($field) {
    if(!preg_match("to:",$field) || !preg_match("cc:",$field) || !preg_match("\r",$field) || !preg_match("\n",$field) || !preg_match("%0A",$field)){ 
        $possiblespam = TRUE;
    }else $possiblespam = FALSE;
    if ($possiblespam) {
        die("Possible spam attempt detected. If this is not the case, please edit the content of the contact form and try again.");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you to whoever is going to answer and help me. Any kind of help is very much appreciated!

Comment: From your "regular expression"s, do you simply want `stripos`?

Comment: TBH, I don't know what the regular expressions were and I'm too lazy to study because I'm in a hurry. What's 'stripos', btw? I've searched through the net and most answers were I should use !preg_match. But there's an error when I use it.

Comment: It seems you only want to know if e.g. "to:" exists in `$field`. If that's true, then it doesn't need RegExp at all. Try `if(stripos($field,"to:")!==false || stripos($field,"cc:")!==false)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to surround the regexes with delimiters:

```
preg_match("/to:/",$field)
     here __^   ^
```

Comment: ^ This worked out well! Thank you very much! :)